# Jquery unusual slideshow

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am creating a bit unusual slideshow which consists of 3 images instead of one, please take a look at this:

[image]

So as i said it's made up of 3 parts, the middle one which is 100% visible and other two which are just 50% visible each, now when you want to change image all three of them slide to either left or right, and the middle one goes to the side and half of it becomes invisible.

Now i have figured how to do that, what im dealing with is that i can't figure out how to know how many times i need to slide say from `1` to `5` or any other number, it's rather hard to explain so i made this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cnYSU/3/

As you can see in that fiddle i just made a lot `if` and it became just a huge mess so there has to be some better way to do this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose this [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/scaillerie/QSC8T/2/) where you can navigate through next/prev and the page number.

Answer (score 1):

here i give you more simple

http://jsfiddle.net/viyancs/Wwr8Z/2/